# How to use Wikipedia API to search for values input by a user?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am new to programming and web development so I don't know how to use the correct Ajax/JSON. I am using HTML and jQuery. I have created text input field with a submit button underneath, I want my page to search for the value in this input field and return results.

I found this jQuery code to do it, but I do not understand the format of the url.

```
$("#search").click(function(){

    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();// value entered by the user
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ searchTerm + "&format=json&callback=?"; // url to look for using the search input by the user

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:url,
        async:true,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data[1][0]);
            console.log(data[2][0]);
            console.log(data[3][0]);
        },

        error: function(errorMessage){alert("Error");}
    });
});
```

the input field is like this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="searchTerm">
<button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: A lot of tutorials are available for ajax. Explaining all of it is out of scope here. Learn it, and try out the Mediawiki API at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial Come back with some code that you have written and we will help you.

Comment: @Chintan I have edited the question, there is a jQuery code here, but I do not understand why "searchTerm" was added to url in that specific position, nor do I know where the URL is obtained from. I tried to read the link you provided, unfortunetly as a beginner and English not being my first language, I'm finding it hard to find my way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things to know about the Wikipedia API.

Consider the url that you have shared:

```
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ searchTerm + "&format=json&callback=?";
```

There are two parts in the API URL.

1. The API Entry Point: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php - This is
   the URL to which you make all your API calls i.e. it is the part
   common to all API calls.
2. Parameters: The rest of the URL are parameters. In the parameters, you specify what exactly you want from the API call. I am explaining some of the parameters below:

`action` parameter: There are many `action` parameters available in the Wikipedia API. `action=query` parameter is used to get information about a wikipedia article. Another common action parameter is `action=opensearch` which is used to search Wikipedia - which is also there in the URL above. To read more on the Action parameter go [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:MediaWiki_action_API).

Each `action` parameter also may have its own sub-parameters. For example, the `search` parameter which is used in the url above. It tells the API what term to search for.

`format` parameter tells which format you want the result in. It is usually `json` though `php` and `xml` are also supported but deprecated. More on this [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats).

`callback=?` may have been added in your query to trigger a JSONP response to avoid violation of [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). More information on Cross Site Requests regarding the Wikipedia API are available [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests).

`

Comment: this is a very helpful answer, thank you very much, I have two questions:
1- what is the "?" added after the API Entry Point?
2- would the same parameters apply to other APIs, for instance I wanted to add a search bar that searches for google images and renders them to the page, do I follow the same procedure?
thanks alot.

Comment: 1. ? is usually added to tell the server/API handler that this is the end of the URL path and whatever comes after this the query parameters. This applies to all URLs. https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url

Comment: 2. No, the same parameters will not apply to all APIs. You need to look up each one's docs for that.
You may accept the answer if it was helpful and refer http://codepen.io/chintanpokhrel/pen/JGZZmg for Wikipedia Search if needed.